# How to get time exceeded icmp header response id?

Tags: c, response, icmp

I am writing a simple traceroute program uses ICMP packets. I have a problem with verification of incoming packets. Before I send a icmp packet I set hcmp header id as a process id. When i got a response I can got icmp header id only when it is replay response. Problem is when it is time exceeded response, becouse i got 0 as a icmp header id. What should I do to get a icmp header id when there is time exceeded? Or maybe there is another way to identify response? I need to know that the response is for my process. Can anybody help me?

my setting icmp header:

```
struct icmphdr setIcmpHdr(int sequence){
  struct icmphdr icmp_header;
  icmp_header.type = ICMP_ECHO;
  icmp_header.code = 0;
  icmp_header.un.echo.id = getpid(); // here I set the id
  icmp_header.un.echo.sequence = sequence;
  icmp_header.checksum = 0;
  icmp_header.checksum = compute_icmp_checksum((u_int16_t*)&icmp_header, 
                          sizeof(icmp_header));
  return icmp_header;
}
```

sending request:

```
int sequence = hop;
struct icmphdr icmp_header = setIcmpHdr(sequence);
struct sockaddr_in recipeint = setRecipient(destination);
int ttl = hop;

setTTLOption(ttl, sockfd);

ssize_t bytes_sent = sendto(sockfd, &icmp_header, sizeof(icmp_header), 0,
                            (struct sockaddr*)&recipeint,sizeof(recipeint));
```

receiving:

```
 //receiving

struct sockaddr_in sender;
socklen_t sender_len = sizeof(sender);
u_int8_t buffer[IP_MAXPACKET];

ssize_t packet_len = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, IP_MAXPACKET, 0, (struct 
                                      sockaddr*)&sender, &sender_len);

char ip_str[20];
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(sender.sin_addr), ip_str, sizeof(ip_str));

struct iphdr* ip_header = (struct iphdr*) buffer;
ssize_t ip_header_len = 4*ip_header->ihl;

u_int8_t* icmp_packet = (buffer + 4 * ip_header->ihl);
struct icmphdr *icmp_header2 = (struct icmphdr *) icmp_packet;

printf("pid: %d\n", icmp_header2->un.echo.id); //here is zero when it is time exceeded ;/
if(icmp_header2->type != 0){ 
     printf("IP packet with ICMP content from %s, hop %d\n\n", ip_str, 
               hop);
}else if(icmp_header2->type == 0){
     printf("Reached destination: %s with %d hops.\n", destination, hop);
     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I will be grateful for any help. :)